# How to make Drawing on Fully Transparent View Visible

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I am using Quartz for drawing as in custom UIView say "Paint"

I have controller view "viewC"

I did

```
[self.view addSubView:somePaintInstance]; in my viewC at some event
```

Now when i am drawing or painting , the default background is "black" for Paint.

I want to do a Full Transparent Painting/Drawing on top of my "viewC" view

So i did

```
somePaintInstance.alpha=0.5; (before adding it as subview)
```

But that also make my drawing/painting transparent with the Paint's Background , so if i make it fully transparent (alpha = 0.0) , i couldn't see the drawing itself with the paint's view

What i tried and not working:

- somePaintInstance.setbackgroundcolor
- somePaintInstance.opaque

Other answers on web are also NOT concrete for this kind of implementation

I looked the answer by rob here:
[How to add a transparent gradient mask to a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236375/how-to-add-a-transparent-gradient-mask-to-a-context)

But Still not clear how do i implement exactly what i want?

Let me know other details if required

Regards,

Comment: I also wonder how to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to set a background with alpha value 0 or to work with StartTransparentLayer. None of that worked.
What worked for me was to set the views opaque property to NO.
In my view's initializer i put the following code:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // set default values
        self.colorNormal = [UIHelper ricolaYellow];
        self.colorActice = [UIColor colorWithHexString:CIRCLE_COLOR_ACTIVE];
        self.capacities = nil;
        self.opaque = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should work,

```
somePaintInstance.backGroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: backGroundColor property is not working at all in this case no matter where i put it , i have a feeling some Quartz specific functions calls are required that will allow the background context to be fully transparent at the same time drawing (context) on it will be NOT.

Comment: alpha = 1.0 for what (context)? can you elaborate

Comment: @user300940. OK. try this, CGContextClearRect(context, viewRect);

Comment: already tried ClearRect will clear the entire context NOT what i want

Comment: what ClearRect do is "just" the opposite , makes my drawing "clear" (invisible) and the default background "black" still remains

Comment: I meant alpha of view. If it doesn work. Alpha of context too. may be via this function, CGContextSetAlpha(CGContextRef c, CGFloat alpha)

Comment: mate you are not getting what i actually want SetAlpha is for Opacity Level Adjustment for the objects drawn on the context , meaning that my drawing will be affected but not the context on which it is drawn,which eventually is the goal